# How to compute Expected Squared Jump Distance (ESJD) of a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: probability, bayesian, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

The **Expected Squared Jump Distance** (ESJD) seems to be defined slightly differently in various papers, which makes this very confusing. For instance, Definition 2.2 of [Optimal Scaling of Random-Walk Metropolis Algorithms on General Target Distributions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.12157.pdf) which in their paper is specific to the Random Walk algorithm, is
$$
\mathbb{E}_\pi\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{N}}[\|X - Y\|^2]
$$

## Question

> Given that you have run a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm starting from $X_0$ and targeting $\pi$ and have generated $X_1, \ldots, X_N$, how can I estimate the ESJD?

## Attempted Solution

I'll define the Metropolis-Hastings kernel as
$$
P(x, dy) = a(x, y) Q(x, dy) + \left[\int (1 - a(x, y))Q(x, dy)\right]\delta_x(dy)
$$
then it is my understanding that the ESJD formal definition is
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\pi\otimes P}[\|Y - X\|^2] = \int \|y - x\|^2 \pi(dx) P(x, dy)
$$
It is assumed that $X\sim \pi$ and $Y \sim P(X, \cdot)$. Notice that $P$ here is the Metropolis-Hastings kernel and **not** the proposal kernel. In a RWM $Q(x, dy) = \mathcal{N}(dy \mid x, \Sigma)$.

Now I tried to find out how to estimate ESJD using the samples I obtained from Metropolis-Hastings, but I have been unsuccessful. My approach is this
$$
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}_{\pi\otimes P}\left[\|Y - X\|^2\right]
    &= \int \|y - x\|^2 a(x,y) \pi(dx) Q(x, dy) + \int \|y - x\|^2 \int \left[\int (1 - a(x, y))Q(x, dy)\right]\pi(dx) \delta_x(dy) \\\\
    &= \int \|y - x\|^2 a(x,y) \pi(dx) Q(x, dy) \\\\
    &= \mathbb{E}_{\pi\otimes Q}\left[\|Y - X\|^2\right].
\end{align}
$$
This looks correct to me, but against my usual intuition. I can consider
$$
(X_0, X_1, \ldots, X_N) \sim \pi(dx_0) \prod_{n=1}^N P(x_{n-1}, dx_n)
$$
and since $\pi = P\pi$ then we know the marginal of each sample is $\pi$ and so I could construct the empirical distribution
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \delta_{X_{n-1}, X_n}(dx_{0:N})
$$
and plug it into the expression for the ESJD but the result is not what I was expecting.

Comment: Basically, I always thought that the ESJD was defined as (gonna give the one for RWM)
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \|X_{n-1} - X_n\|^2 \min\left(1, \frac{\pi(X_{n})}{\pi(X_{n-1})}\right)
$$
or maybe without $1/N$, but what I get is different.

Comment: $\|X_{n-1} - X_n\|^2$ is the square of a distance.

Comment: @Xi'an if you were referring to the double norm, I used it because initially stackexchange was showing me absolute values. I think it was a problem with my browser. Do oyu know which of the two formulations is correct?
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \|X_n - X_{n-1}\|^2
$$
or 
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \|X_{n-1}^* - X_{n-1}\|^2 a(X_{n-1}, X_{n-1}^*)
$$
where $X_{n-1}$ is the state of the Markov Chain at step $n$, $X_{n-1}^*$ is the proposal, and $X_n$ is the state of the Markov chain at step $n$. Also $a(X_{n-1}, X_{n-1}^*)$ is the metropolis-hastings acceptance function.

Comment: @Xi'an Both estimators I wrote above have the same expectation, and approximate the same quantity. I suppose with the second option you probably tend to get a better estimate because you can use also all those proposals that lead to a rejection to estimate the ESJD, as long as they had positive acceptance probability

Comment: The second estimator is a Rao-Blackwellized version hence with a smaller variance.